# Do I have to refer to the participants in the main body of research report?

Tags: writing

In my research paper, I took interviews from people. So in the main body in which there will be different headings, I have to compare the answers and then form a conclusion (under each heading). Do I refer to the participants in each heading?

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE. This might be better-answered at our sister sites for [Writers.SE](http://writers.stackexchange.com/) or perhaps  [Academia.SE](http://academia.stackexchange.com/), as this stack is more oriented towards learning the mechanical aspects of the language.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Academia SE

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how many interviews you took, it would probably be best to write an introduction in which you introduce your topic and participants. You can then compare the answers in the paragraphs of the body of your text.

However, if you're writing separate paragraphs for each interviewee's answer, you could introduce the heading of each paragraph.

Comment: I will make separate headings for each question. And the questionnaire is same for all participants.Do I mention there names or use "participants"/"respondent"  instead?. Also the recommendations the participants will give, can I sum them up under recommendation heading without referring to the participants?